# Android NavigationView click only small area

Tags: android

I have created the default template with menu from android studio. This project is working now but sometimes a user can click on meny only on small area:

[image]

But sometimes all items in menu work fine(each of item has normal area for click listener), It happens randomly.

Maybu someone has this problem, i cant understand why it happens.

My code:

xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/view_nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

activity_main_drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_overview"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_overview"
            android:title="@string/overview" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_library"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_library"
            android:title="@string/library_of_events" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_statistic"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_chart"
            android:title="@string/view_your_stats" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_add_event"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_add_event"
            android:title="@string/create_a_new_event" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings"
            android:title="@string/settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_export"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_table"
            android:title="@string/data_export" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_help"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_help"
            android:title="@string/help" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

activity has default template code

```
public class MainActivity extends TimeActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);

  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(this);

}

@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected " + String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_overview:
                openOverview();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_library:
                openEventsLibrary();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_statistic:
                openStatistic();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_add_event:
                openAddEvent();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                openSettings();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_export:
                openDataExport();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_help:
                VideoActivity.start(this, false);
                //youTubePopUp.show(view);
                break;
            default:
                openWelcome(0);
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View view) {
        Utils.hideKeyboard(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View view) {

    }

}
```